# About the lifespan of Deep Link - How long will the processing when the app is owned be cached?

Tags: ios, web, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I have a question about the time that DeepLink is cached.
I created a QR code using the URL generated with Dynamic Link. After reading the QR code with a camera, it is decided whether to open an iOS app or a web page.
At this time, a problem occurs when the user executes the following flow.

1. A user who does not have the iOS App scans the QR code and opens the WebPage.
2. Close the webpage and download the target app from the App Store.
3. When you open the downloaded app, the scheme process specified by Dynamic Link runs.

I think the cause is probably that Deep Link processing is cached.
How long will this cache remain?
Also, is there a way to prevent the app from executing the scheme startup process once the WebPage is opened?

I would appreciate it if you could let me know.